# In Hapi.js can I redirect to a different endpoint and set a statusCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-status-codes, hapi.js

If a user is not authenticated to view a particular route (e.g: `/admin`) Auth throws a `Boom unorthorized` error I want to be able to re-direct to the `/login` but still return the `401` HTTP `statusCode`.

we have tried the following code:

```
const statusCode =  request.output.payload.statusCode;

if(statusCode && statusCode === 401) {
  return reply.redirect('/login').code(statusCode);
}
```

The *redirect* works when we remove the `.code(statusCode)` but we would *ideally* *like* to return the `401` code to the client not `302` (*redirect*)

***Or***... would it be "***best practice***" to return `302`...?

> Context: we are developing a little (*re-useable*) plugin to handle errors in our Hapi App/API and one of the features is to `redirect` to `/login` when auth fails see: https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-error#redirecting-to-another-endpoint and we want to get it "*right*" so others can use it!

Comment: Taking into account your context addition, my response on best-practice is still my position on how you should implement. Replying with a 401 when you're redirecting the user is out of line with the HTTP spec because you're handling the unauthorized access error yourself. Honestly, the use of 302 is also incorrect (Hapi should use 303 See Other), but it's been accepted by the web community for so long that it's considered normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the HapiJS source that's causing you grief (lib/response.js:320):

```
internals.Response.prototype.redirect = function (location) {

    this.statusCode = 302;
    this.location(location);
    this.temporary = this._temporary;
    this.permanent = this._permanent;
    this.rewritable = this._rewritable;
    return this;
};
```

As you can see, by using `reply.redirect()` Hapi is already replying a 302 code. You'll need to decide whether to reply with a 401 and redirect on the front end, or use the Hapi redirect and accept that it conforms to the protocol standards.

As an answer to the best practice bit, yes, Hapi is doing exactly what is expected when a server forces a redirect (302 Redirect). In order to use a 401 response, the best practice is to redirect on the client side as if you were simply navigating to the route normally.

For reference, the reply.redirect() function definition (lib/reply.js:145) is simply

`return this.response('').redirect(location);`

EDIT Dec '16: Kelly Milligan below pointed out that using `reply.redirect().code()` is now supported by HapiJS and won't send a 302 status if you don't want it to.